# Forecasting with regression in R

Tags: r, time-series, linear-regression, forecasting

I need to do forecasting graph with regression in R but seems like my the output I get does not say much.
[forecasting plot with regression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lhc3h.png)

The image above is my output. The x-axis shows the obervations. I have 756 observations and my time series data is from 2015-2021. For each year, there are about 35 observations. I need to have year as my x-axis instead of observations.

```
library(forecast)
fcast <- forecast(ts_model, newdata=data.frame(df_new2))
fcast <- forecast(ts_model)
plot(fcast)

> dput(head(df_new2))
structure(list(Year = c(2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015), 
Age = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), Race = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), Gender = 

c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Life_expectancy = c(71.2, 70.8, 66.9, 62, 
57.1, 52.3)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

#Time series linear regression model
library(fpp)
library(forecast)
ts_df = as.ts(df_new2)
ts_model <- tslm(Life_expectancy ~ Age + Gender+Race, 
data=ts_df)
```

Comment: You're more likely to find an answer if you include a reproducible example. Can you include some data using `dput()` or add code to show how `ts_model` was created?

Comment: @nrennie. I have added some codes.